# Error when launching JavaFX 2.2 Application with Java Web Start

Tags: java, javafx-2, java-web-start, jnlp

I developed a JavaFX 2.2 application. I packaged and signed the JAR and wrote the JNLP by hand (see below).

The Problem is, that i can't start the application with Java Web Start; for example by double-clicking the .jnlp-file.

I'm facing the following error message: *Unable to find class: xxxx.pamoja.client.RichClientApplication*

It is no problem to start the application with:

```
java -jar pamoja-rich-client.jar
```

or by double-clicking the JAR file.

Therefore, i know that the application works in general. So i guess the problem is related to Java Web Start.

I spent a lot of time "googling around" but didn't find any information applicable to my problem.

Has someone an idea? I'm grateful for any hints!

**The JAR looks like this:**

```
jar
 |- META-INF
 |     |- MANIFEST.MF
 |     |- PAMOJA.RSA
 |     |- PAMOJA.SF
 |
 |- com
     |- javafx
     |    |- main
     |        |- Main.class
     |        |- NoJavaFXFallback.class
     |
     |- xxxxx
          |- pamoja
                |- client
                      |- RichClientApplication.class
                      |- main.css
                      |- main.fxml
                      |- ...
```

**The Manifest (before signing):**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
JavaFX-Version: 2.2
JavaFX-Application-Class: xxxx.pamoja.client.RichClientApplication
JavaFX-Fallback-Class: com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback
Main-Class: com.javafx.main.Main
```

**The JNLP:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" href="pamoja-rich-client.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Pamoja Rich Client</title>
    <vendor>kKdH</vendor>
    <description></description>
    <icon href="icon.png"/>
</information>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="pamoja-rich-client.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
</resources>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<application-desc name="Pamoja Rich Client"/>
<update check="always" policy="prompt-run"/>
</jnlp>
```

**Java:**

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode, sharing)
```

---

**UPDATE**

I added the codebase attribute as following:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" href="pamoja-rich-client.jnlp" codebase="http://localhost:8080/">
```

And JavaFX as resource:

```
<resources os="Windows">
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
</resources>
```

The error message *Unable to find class: xxxx.pamoja.client.RichClientApplication* is gone. But now it throws the following NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.javafx.main.Main.getAppArguments(Main.java:506)
at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:860)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You need to specify the codebase attribute in your jnlp tag and point it at the URL from which you download the jnlp file. This is then used for all relative href attributes in your jnlp file.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem! Two things were necessary:

1. the **codebase** attribute.
2. the **< jfx:javafx-desc >** tag to specify the class which implements the JavaFX application class. Java Web Start can start the JavaFX application straightly without a special 'launcher' Main class.

The final JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" href="pamoja-rich-client.jnlp" codebase="http://localhost:8080/">
    <information>
        <title>Pamoja Rich Client</title>
        <vendor>kKdH</vendor>
        <description></description>
        <icon href="icon.png"/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="pamoja-rich-client.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <application-desc name="Pamoja Rich Client"/>
    <jfx:javafx-desc  main-class="xxxx.pamoja.client.RichClientApplication" name="RichClientApplication" />
    <update check="always" policy="prompt-run"/>
</jnlp>
```

I don't know whether it works in general without specifying the JavaFX runtime as resource. Maybe it fails with older Java version.

Answer (score 4):

Your JNLP file is invalid. Have a look at the Oracle reference for the JNLP file format: [JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)

The error I can directly spot is the missing `codebase` attribute in your JNLP tag.

Comment: According to [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/deployingWithoutCodebase.html#launchWebStartApplication) i thought i can omit the codebase.

Comment: Well, that would work if you include the jnlp like shown there (so that Java Webstart can guess the codebase from the url it is downloading the JNLP from. I would not trust this mechanism, and I had trouble with this on two occasions recently.

Comment: AFAIU the 'can leave out codebase' only applies to applets, which this is definitely not.  The JNLP also has sections in the wrong order & requires further attention.

Answer (score 4):

Your jnlp does not look correct. And you need to add a reference to JavaFX - for example for Windows:

```
<resources os="Windows">
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Is that resource really needed since Java FX is already shipped with Java 7 (and that is the required version according to JNLP)?

Comment: @Matthias Yes I think it is required because JavaFX is not on the classpath by default. It is not necessary with Java 8 though.

Answer (score 2):

Don't manually generate the jnlp, instead [use the JavaFX packaging tools to automatically generate the jnlp](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABFECGG) and, once that works, you can manually tweak the jnlp if you wish.